# image in string-array list preference

Tags: android, xml, image, preferences, arrays

I wanted to add an image instead of string for listPreferences, 
i tried inserted ImageView b/w the item tags but it gave an error too,

I just want to display images instead of text besides the radio buttons
http://s15.postimg.org/qozfmtu3v/Capture.png

```
<string-array name="themeList">
   <item>@drawable/theme_green</item>
    <item>@drawable/theme_pink</item>
    <item></item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: You should probably use an `<integer-array>` instead of a `<string-array>` as `@drawable/theme_green` represents an `int` and not a `string`.

Comment: Well post the code, where you're setting the `ImageView` from the `<integer-array>` - not much to go on, when you only posted the XML :-)